# Require ('ffi') throws error in Electron application

Tags: node.js, electron, react-boilerplate, node-ffi

I am working on an Electron.js application and need to use the `node-ffi` module to use  a С++ dll library. I have installed the module and tried to add `require('ffi')` into my  `app\electron\main.dev.js`, but got an error:

> ```
> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The
> "path" argument must be of type string. Received type object...
> ```

The `require('ffi')` works as expected, for example, in this simple [project](https://github.com/noseratio/electron-quick-start)

After some invesigation I have found, that Error is triggered in `...node_modules\bindings\bindings.js`:

```js
exports.getRoot = function getRoot (file) {
  var dir = dirname(file) // here!
```

`file` is undefined here...

My project is [here](https://github.com/AndrewPM/ElectronReactBoilerplate4).

Full Error Message:

> ```
> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The >"path" argument must be of type string. Received type object
>    at assertPath (path.js:39:11)
>    at dirname (path.js:651:5)
>    at Function.getRoot 
> (D:\JavaScript\ElectronReactBoilerplate4\app\electron\main.prod.js:482:13)
>    at bindings 
> (D:\JavaScript\ElectronReactBoilerplate4\app\electron\main.prod.js:391:32)
>    at Object../node_modules/ref/lib/ref.js 
> (D:\JavaScript\ElectronReactBoilerplate4\app\electron\main.prod.js:7148:102)
>    at _webpack_require__ 
> (D:\JavaScript\ElectronReactBoilerplate4\app\electron\main.prod.js:21:30)
>    at Object../node_modules/ffi/lib/ffi.js 
> (D:\JavaScript\ElectronReactBoilerplate4\app\electron\main.prod.js:2619:11)
>    at _webpack_require__ 
> (D:\JavaScript\ElectronReactBoilerplate4\app\electron\main.prod.js:21:30)
>    at App.<anonymous> 
> (D:\JavaScript\ElectronReactBoilerplate4\app\electron\main.prod.js:196:3)
>    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)...
> ```

What a magic is going here?

How to get the `require('ffi')` working in my project?

Edited:
 ... replaced `false` in `internals\webpack\webpack.main.dev.js`  with `true`

```js
node: {
    __dirname: true,
    __filename: true,
  },
```

and now  Error message is

> ```
> (node:16996) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried:
>  тЖТ D:\AndrewReactElectron\ElectronReactBoilerplate4\app\build\binding.node
>  тЖТ D:\AndrewReactElectron\ElectronReactBoilerplate4\app\build\Debug\binding.node
>  тЖТ D:\AndrewReactElectron\ElectronReactBoilerplate4\app\build\Release\binding.node
>  тЖТ D:\AndrewReactElectron\ElectronReactBoilerplate4\app\out\Debug\binding.node
>  тЖТ D:\AndrewReactElectron\ElectronReactBoilerplate4\app\Debug\binding.node
>  тЖТ D:\AndrewReactElectron\ElectronReactBoilerplate4\app\out\Release\binding.node
>  тЖТ D:\AndrewReactElectron\ElectronReactBoilerplate4\app\Release\binding.node
>  тЖТ D:\AndrewReactElectron\ElectronReactBoilerplate4\app\build\default\binding.node
>  тЖТ D:\AndrewReactElectron\ElectronReactBoilerplate4\app\compiled\10.11.0\win32\ia32\binding.node
>  тЖТ D:\AndrewReactElectron\ElectronReactBoilerplate4\app\addon-build\release\install-root\binding.node
>  тЖТ D:\AndrewReactElectron\ElectronReactBoilerplate4\app\addon-build\debug\install-root\binding.node
>  тЖТ D:\AndrewReactElectron\ElectronReactBoilerplate4\app\addon-build\default\install-root\binding.node
>  тЖТ D:\AndrewReactElectron\ElectronReactBoilerplate4\app\lib\binding\node-v69-win32-ia32\binding.node
>     at bindings (D:\AndrewReactElectron\ElectronReactBoilerplate4\app\electron\main.prod.js:445:9)
> ```
>
> Any ideas?

Comment: are you actually using `require'ffi'`? That's not `require('ffi')`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `externals: { ffi: 'ffi' }`  into  my   `webpack.main.prod.js` has solved the problem